# How to remove whitespaces and linebreaks from specific parts of a string?

Tags: c#, string

So my question is this, lets say for example I have a string:

```
a b c d e f g
```

I want to remove any spaces or line breaks between a b and c only but leave the rest like they are. Essentially what it should look like for the above example is this:

```
abcd e f g
```

I know how to replace whitespaces and line breaks in an entire string using the `replace` method but not sure how I would do it for a specific part of the string. Any help will be appreciated!

EDIT: (for stefankmitph)

Input:

```
hello my name is martin
I am from Paris in France
```

Current Output:

```
hellomynameis martin  I am from Paris in France
```

Expected Output:

```
hellomynameis martin I am from Paris in France
```

It is adding two whitespaces for a linebreak, I'm not sure why

Comment: What is the criterion for determining what whitespace is appropriate?  It sounds like you should focus on breaking your string apart based on that criterion and removing the whitespace from only the pieces you want it removed from.

Comment: look at the methods inside a C# string class on msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_methods(v=vs.110).aspx IndexOf, SubString or Split and create a new string from selected pieces?

Comment: What would be the output if the input is `b c a d e f`?

Comment: Initially, my gut response is that if you know what your Strings are, then create substrings and remove whitespace from the appropriate substring and then re-concatenate.  But, echoing David's sentiments, the problem statement is a bit vague, so I don't know if this is a solution that would work.

Comment: @AvinashRaj It should get rid of spaces and linebreaks between the first 4 letters. The letter doesn't matter. a b c d e f g was just an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with LINQ:

```
string s = "a b c d e f g";
var split = s.Split();
string joined = string.Concat(split.Take(3)) + string.Join(" ", split.Skip(3));
```

**EDIT** for your second example:

```
string s = @"hello my name is martin
I am from Paris in France";

var split = s.Split(new[] {" ", Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None);

string part1 = string.Concat(split.Take(3));
string part2 = string.Join(" ", split.Skip(3));
string joined = string.Format("{0} {1}", part1, part2);
```

This should work now as expected.

Comment: Just tried your method, instead of keeping the whitespace in rest of the string, its adding one more. so I'm getting something like abcd  e  f  g. So two whitespaces between d and e and f and g.

Answer (score 1):

> It should get rid of spaces and linebreaks between the first 4 letters. The letter doesn't matter.

You can do it with regex, matching the first four letters into capturing groups, and then using them as replacements:

```
var r = Regex.Replace("a b c d e f g", @"^(\w)\s*(\w)\s*(\w)\s*(\w)", "$1$2$3$4");
```

This regular expression has four groups numbered 1 through 4. The groups consist of letters, and they are separated by zero or more whitespace. Replace takes captured groups, and places then together with no whitespace around them.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/WpJGjn)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Regex.Replace` function.

```
Regex.Replace(str, @"(?s)(?<=^(?:\s*\S){4})(.*)|\s", "$1");
```

[RegexStrom](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C%3D%5E(%3F%3A%5Cs*%5CS)%7B4%7D)(.*)%7C%5Cs&i=a%20b%20c%20d%20e%20f%20g&r=%241)